# Failing a very simple program in both ways

Tags: c, eclipse, printf, scanf, nios

I'm surprised that Eclipse can fail to run the simplest program in not only one way but in many way at the same time. The program is

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  int  n; 
  while (scanf("%d", &n) > 0)
  {
    printf("%d\n", n);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Failure 1: When run in the simulator the output is displayed twice for no reason. The output should be displayed once.

Failure 2: When run with the DE2 board then output is not displayed at all.

Why can't my environment perform like it should?

Comment: These complex IDE's always have issues. I've never liked any of them. My IDE is vi. It works pretty dependably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't give many details I'm just guessing:

1. there could be some kind of echoing enabled
2. on embedded systems `<stdio.h>` is not required to be supported. `<stdio.h>` is guaranteed to be available only in *hosted environments* (i.e. under control of an OS), not in *freestanding environments* (bare metal).

Quoting from the C99 draft standard N1256:

> ### 4. Conformance
>
> [...]
>
> 6
>
> The two forms of conforming implementation are hosted and freestanding. A conforming
>   hosted implementation shall accept any strictly conforming program. A conforming
>   freestanding implementation shall accept any strictly conforming program that does not
>   use complex types and in which the use of the features specified in the library clause
>   (clause 7) is confined to the contents of the standard headers `<float.h>`,
>   `<iso646.h>`, `<limits.h>`, `<stdarg.h>`, `<stdbool.h>`, `<stddef.h>`, and
>   `<stdint.h>`. A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional
>   library functions), provided they do not alter the behavior of any strictly conforming
>   program.

You should check the documentation of the compiler for your board to see which headers it supports.